# Monotouch Databinding

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, uilabel

How to bind a observable property to UIlabel or UITextField in monotouch

`TextField.Bind()` exists but i can't use.

here is the parameters:

```
UILabel.Bind (string binding, NSObject observable, string keyPath, NSDictionary options)
```

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding Objective-C documentation is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

The important bits that you need to know is what is the value that you will monitoring (binding) and what is the keyPath that is reachable from the "observable" as `keyPath'.   Once you have those, you can fill in the rest.